# Geometry Nodes - Instances on Geometry withtout Geometry after Faces Materials grab

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have a node where each Instances have the same material than my geometry faces but I don't want to keep my geometry (the sphere in the simple example). I want to hide or delete it.
I have try different node like separate geometry and delete geometry but can't find the way...

Thanks !

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the boolean attribute you already captured after instancing on points to preserve the the instanced geometry and delete the original surface like so: [image]

You just need to add a Boolean Math node to invert the selection and use the "Not" operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot James, you're the Boss ! :)